# How to select elements with exact one class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

so I have,

```
<ul>

<li class="foo">
abc
</li>

<li class="foo bar">
def
</li>

</ul>
```

If I do `$('.foo').css('font-size','x-large');`

this will change both li elements with the large font. How could I select the class with "foo" only but not "bar"?

Thanks!

Comment: `select the class with "foo" only but not "bar"` is the only condition you need to validate or there can be other conbinations?

Comment: just "foo" thanks.  raina's solution worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the following attribute selector, I suppose:

```
$('li[class=foo]');
```

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jKgqK/) to play with. )

Comment: You could also negate only some: `$(".foo").not(".bar")` or `$(".foo:not(.bar)")` http://jsfiddle.net/tRLAP/

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$('.foo:first').css('font-size','x-large');
```